# Synchronizing player's units in a TD flash game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, networking, rtmfp

Im sort of new to the "net world", what I want to develop is a multiplayer TD game, and Im concerned about how to sync the players, I mean, its possible that at some times the map would be crowed with units everywhere.. is that an issue that has to be considered in order to make all players view the same at all times?.

Im planing to use RTMFP.

Thanks!

Comment: Look deeper into `SharedObject.getRemote ()` property. And yes RTMFP is a good way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

What about making your game deterministic? It requires much less bandwidth. Have the game loop run at 10FPS or so triggered by timer, and then just report when you build or upgrade a tower. Latency: maybe only process it once per second, and if you do something on 15.33s tell the other player (and you too) to process it at exactly 17s. Ping desyncs solved!

Comment: Thats exactly mi idea, just send a "broadcast" when players do something relevant to eacth other.